# Link hidden directories

Tags: linux, directory, symlink

I would like to completely link `/root/.vidoes/` to the new directory `/home/videos/`

If a script tries to read/update/save a file to /root/.vidoes/ for example `/root/.vidoes/newvideo.mp4` then it should be saved to `/home/videos/newvideo.mp4` this also needs to be the case for hidden files or directories trying to be accessed from `/root/.vidoes/xyz`

I've tried `ln -s /home/video/ /root/.video/` but that just makes a directory in `/root/.video/video` that links to `/home/video`

Comment: ln -s /home/video/ /root/.video/ - But that just makes a directory in /root/.video/video that links to /home/video

Comment: That's a good start. Please add it to your question so we can (all) see what you have tried.

Comment: If you have gnu tools then `ln` supports some flags to reduce this type of error. `ln -T /home/videos .videos`. You still have to move stuff as in @roaima's answer. It should produce an error if you don't instead of doing the wrong thing. (there is also a `-t` option, see manual). The `-T` and `-t` options are in Gnu `ln`, `cp` and `mv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example command creates `/root/.video/video` instead of linking as expected, you appear to have both directories already present

1. Move everything that is in `/root/.videos` to `/home/videos`

   ```
   mv /root/.videos/* /home/videos    # Assumes no files beginning with a dot
   ```
2. Remove the `/root/.videos` directory

   ```
   rmdir /root/.videos                # If this fails, check no files are still hiding in here
   ```
3. Link the existing directory

   ```
   cd /root
   ln -s /home/videos .videos
   ```

Comment: This comes back as **ls: cannot access '.videos': No such file or directory** on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @masterq He had a typo. It's fixed now.